# Could ethics be grounded in a law of nature?

Tags: ethics, metaethics, social-ethics, moral-agency, moral-realism

Assuming that morality is objective, is it possible that the reason there are moral truths (i.e it is wrong to harm children) is because of an undiscovered law of nature (like gravity)?

Comment: FWIW, "natural law" and "law of nature" don't mean the same thing. "Natural law" basically means something like ethics. "Law of nature" refers to things like the Law of Gravity. To avoid confusion, you should change the title to use "law of nature".

Comment: That is what [metaphysical moral realists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_realism) argue, that some basic moral truths *are* laws of nature, or rather laws of reality ("nature" may be too narrow a term).

Comment: Assuming logic only applies to propositions which bear truth only when there're some state of affairs obtain, per the well-known [Frege–Geach problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expressivism#The_Frege%E2%80%93Geach_problem) in ethics field, the meaning of moral language can then be ultimately grounded in laws of nature via such propositions. Alternatively, you can simply argue by the potential of physical effect via other agents' counter-action one will encounter after committing immoral actions, which must be ultimately grounded in some physiological or psychological laws of nature...